# phantomjs not finding element mvc

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have an mvc app to test and my code works with Chrome but not Phantom.  It can't find a simple input control with id = "password" on the logon page.  I've tried different selectors, xpath, by class, by ID, even different controls on the page.  It can find the "body" tag and the very next, but nothing is working to find anything past the next level in

I've also tried driver.waitforpageload and thread.sleep to make sure things are loaded first, no avail.  Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

> It can't find a simple input control with id = "password" on the logon
>   page.

and

> It can find the "body" tag and the very next inside tag
>   "app-controller", but nothing is working to find anything past the
>   next level in, the view-manager tag.

and

> I've even tested google.com to see if it was even loading and it can
>   find controls on that page successfully.

Considering the above, I'm guessing that the Login page is your page in your site after navigating to the URL.

I have encountered the same issue which normally led me think that PhantomJS cannot identify the elements on page. This until I started debugging stuff.

Because of the way how PhantomJS works loading everything headless, more or less in his own 'container' it turned out that it wasn't even able to load my test site, because it didn't had all the necessary prerequisites executed.

To be able to debug, and check if you face the same issue, just print to a log file the content of your page.
You can achieve this by using: `var pageSource = driver.Pagesource;`
It's highly likely that the last node present will be the `body` one.

If that's the case, you need to see what prerequisites are required for your site to start working: authentication, HTTPS certificates, etc.

Comment: So what was your solution?

Comment: So I looked at the page source and searched for my password or username and the only ones found are the javascript variables.  I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: As I said, this depends what are the prerequisites for your site. In my case, we're using a SQLite DB that I need to create, create the HTTPS thumbprint certificate used and start the custom web server that we're using. Without the developers help, it will be difficult to figure out what you need in order to make it work.

Comment: Thanks it looks like its using polymer which may not play nice with phantom..if u have any ideas for that.